# Execution difference of method call in MainNet vs TestNet

Tags: solidity, testnets, contract-debugging

I was looking at the new smart contracts submitted list on Etherscan to pass the afternoon, and I came across this one:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x70bf9df6967dc96156e76cc43b928a7ef02e159a

The contract seems to be a simple game of Q&A, but I noticed the original answer could be seen in plain sight here:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb479a806fd83e528e635c285b7302a28f0119c4be90ed37232c385bb855f8584

The answer reads "A phonE", and I thought it would get stolen quickly, since I can't be the only one doing this. I decided to take it, contact the owner, and return it to safety. I made some tests on the TestNet to see if everything worked (you need to send 1 ETH to submit a message), and it went fine. This is the testing contract address, you can check the transactions to see the process I was going to follow:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x69e0d22469f654467bcf5c021f3e2162df96e099

As you can see, everything went fine, so I decided to do it on the MainNet. However, even though the messages and all are correct, it ate my ETH and nothing happened. I have accepted the loss of the Ether, but I am wondering, why would it not work, even tho it did on the TestNet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a [blog post](https://blog.b9lab.com/a-bad-case-of-jumping-to-conclusions-too-fast-fc8ad803f9a9) to relate your misadventure in more detail. Here is what happened:

- Using their [first account](https://etherscan.io/address/0x63c47c0ed26c5b3d220cdb60c16bf8266d081293), they deployed a [`HiddenQuestionSender` contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6006e404c8adf05891144b41c9602c353c9e493b), which passes through commands, with [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x35269c7ab13977d996b04ef335a04e04f76da8d56d93c0a59eed7b5e2a4be034).
- 12 days later, using their [second account](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0342e858974faad4ce0c5d9d3b2a14a4fe958d78), they deploy their [`X_GAME` contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x70bf9df6967dc96156e76cc43b928a7ef02e159a) with [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb1b4575c0724fe45c817d269f8e967e061eb424b0b9a49b6d131c96885031c88).
- Right after that, using their first account, they tell `HiddenQuestionSender` to set up the question, `StartGame` with 0 Ether, and change the hash, `NewQuestion`, with [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf1df0e4113cdd8e864235ff2bbd472c98703794ae10e923cd51c8aea260f102a). In the call data, you can see the question but not the answer; but it doesn’t matter in the end. You can also find the new fake hash: `0xaee11ed86334ac3afdac440921f36b90a937dfbc02f43b02a81b763b769fca4a`.
- Right after that again, using their second account, they call `StartGame` with 1.03 Ether with [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb479a806fd83e528e635c285b7302a28f0119c4be90ed37232c385bb855f8584#decodetab). Notice the `TxReceipt Status: Success`.
- Later, you tried your luck with [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x99391d0b9fff880db870325ce7e929440770a8e868f31b7b74683192f8e93c95) and 1.01 Ether. You lost it to the contract.
- At some point, they collected their rewards, with [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0f0bad6b4f978682ea837fbbe9c8cdf5611a0155e9e5c44d919dae6e5b65cc1f), which is also listed in the [internal transactions of `X_GAME`](https://etherscan.io/address/0x70bf9df6967dc96156e76cc43b928a7ef02e159a#internaltx). It’s the only one there, and is too late to alert you.

For others reading this, it would have been possible to detect something fishy earlier with `web3.eth.getStorageAt(X_GAME.address, slotIndex)` and:

- At slot `1`, find out that `questionSender` is not their address but strangely that of a smart contract: `HiddenQuestionSender`
- At slot `2`, find out that `responseHash` does not match `web3.sha3(“A phonE”)`

You could also have used Ganache to `--fork` from the main net and safely test the outcome of your own *attack*.

Comment: Bless you my man. This should be made public knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you fell for this!

`NewQuestion` was called before you attempted to take the ether.

I believe this is the transaction that did it: https://www.etherchain.org/tx/f1df0e4113cdd8e864235ff2bbd472c98703794ae10e923cd51c8aea260f102a/parityTrace. Search for 0x3e3ee859, which is the function selector for `NewQuestion(string,bytes32)`.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'll remove that bit from the answer.

Comment: Is that present on Etherscan? If not, that's a bug that would need to be fixed

Comment: Sure, https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xf1df0e4113cdd8e864235ff2bbd472c98703794ae10e923cd51c8aea260f102a&type=parity#raw.

Comment: The honeypot takes advantage of the fact that Etherscan doesn't list all passed messages in "internal transactions." I think the specific limitation here is that messages with 0 ether attached aren't listed.

Comment: Oh man, I didn't know that. I supposed the smart contract thaat received my ETH had something to do. Shouldn't that be fixed on Etherscan's end?

Comment: I don't know Etherscan's rationale for what they do. You might want to contact them and ask.

Comment: I will definitely contact them. This is unacceptable for the most widely used Ethereum chain explorer, unless there's a major reason for it.